# DataTables - PHP while loop issue can't find the last result and add new TR

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I am using DataTables and I want to add new `TR` at the end of while loop.

I know we can add `<tfoot></tfoot>`, but I don't want to add '' because I am filtering data with custom Ajax.

I have tried below code but it's not working:

```
<?php
    $Itesres = mysqli_query($con_db,"SELECT * FROM tbl_area ORDER BY `tbl_area`.`name` ASC");
    while($ItemResult = mysqli_fetch_array($Itesres)){
?>
<table id="printData" class="table table-bordered table-hover ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Group</th>
        <th>Party Name</th>
        <th>Balance</th> 
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="getGroups">
    <?php
        $i = 1;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sdetails)){
        $totalAmount += $row['total_debtors'];
        $i++;
    ?>  
        <tr>
            <td><a href="view_debtors_area.php?auth=<?php echo $salt_key_check.'&lid='.$row['area_id']; ?>"><?php echo getAreaName($row['area_id']); ?></a></td>
            <td><?php echo GrabAccountIDName($row['client_id']); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo abs($row['total_debtors']); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php if( $i == ( $numRows  - 1 ) ) { ?>            
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="text-align:right">Total:</td>
                <td><?php echo abs($totalAmount); ?></td>
            </tr>

    <?php }  }  ?>          
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Also, when I use `<tfoot></tfoot>` it's not printable.

Comment: Can your totals row be calculated based on the DataTable data client side?

Comment: Is there any reason you cook up your table's HTML server-side, instead of letting DataTables carry out that task for you? I think, that would make your code much cleaner if you would sort out that mess of PHP, HTML, JavaScript into separate scripts.

Comment: @user11299053 no it's not calculated on the DataTable? I'm calculating manually.

Comment: I see that from your code, my (first) question was rather *'Are there necessary inputs to calculate those totals'* user-side? Or you do not transfer underpinning data to your DataTable and there's no way to calculate that user-end.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem is in `$numRows` which is not defined.

So you can try this:

```
<?php
    $Itesres = mysqli_query($con_db,"SELECT * FROM tbl_area ORDER BY `tbl_area`.`name` ASC");
    $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($Itesres);
    while($ItemResult = mysqli_fetch_array($Itesres)){
?>
<table id="printData" class="table table-bordered table-hover ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Group</th>
        <th>Party Name</th>
        <th>Balance</th> 
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="getGroups">
    <?php
        $i = 1;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sdetails)){
        $totalAmount += $row['total_debtors'];
        $i++;
    ?>  
        <tr>
            <td><a href="view_debtors_area.php?auth=<?php echo $salt_key_check.'&lid='.$row['area_id']; ?>"><?php echo getAreaName($row['area_id']); ?></a></td>
            <td><?php echo GrabAccountIDName($row['client_id']); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo abs($row['total_debtors']); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php if( $i == ( $numRows  - 1 ) ) { ?>            
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="text-align:right">Total:</td>
                <td><?php echo abs($totalAmount); ?></td>
            </tr>

    <?php }  }  ?>          
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have mentioned the `$numRows`. But it's not working in the `dataTables`.

Comment: You have just changed the variable name, but I have tried already and it's not working for me, because I am using `dataTables`.

Comment: I changed variable that I pass to function. Echo it and tell what is inside please. I mean $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($Itesres); echo $numRows;

Comment: Just leave it as I am telling you, I am using jQuery `dataTables` to show the result, so you need to first go the `dataTables`.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "first go the dataTables?"